# LibreOffice Calc - Background Fill Options All White

Tags: desktop-background, libreoffice

Whenever I try to modify a cell background in calc (Format>Format Cell>Background), all of the color options are set to white. How do I get the palette back?

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 with LibreOffice 3.5.2.2 Build ID: 350m1(Build:202).

Answer (score 2):

Try to reset the user profile!

**How to reset LibreOffice user Profile?**

- Make sure LibreOffice is closed.
- Open your home directory and Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to show the hidden files and folders.
- Now navigate to /.config/libreoffice/3/user/
- Rename "registrymodifications.xcu" to "registrymodifications.xcu.old".
- Now start LibreOffice (Any application e.g LibreOffice Calc).
- LibreOffice will automatically create a new user profile.

In case you want to restore the old user profile, Just delete the newly created "registrymodifications.xcu" and rename "registrymodifications.xcu.old" to "registrymodifications.xcu"

Answer (score 0):

The palettes are located in your user profile, at `.config/libreoffice3/user/config/`. Additionally, there's a set of palettes in `/opt/libreoffice3.5/presets/config/`. Take a look for files ending with `.soc` - all those files are palettes. I assume you will have to restore `standard.soc` in your user profile.